# App crashes on simulator but works fine in device after upgrading to lion

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios-simulator

My app is working fine on simulator all the while until i upgraded to OS Lion & xcode Version 4.1.

Now I got the error below.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS
warning: Unable to restore previously selected frame.

But It's working fine on iPhone.
Appreciate for any suggestion ...

Comment: Have you downloaded the Xcode for LionOS ?

Comment: What were you doing while your App crashes?

Comment: i downloaded xcode 4.1. Anyway I sovled the problem. It's Location service. Thanks for your help though ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error that means you're doing something wrong and dealing with either released or uninitialized objects. These errors don't always show up, and when they do, they show up well after the actual infraction. My point is this, just because its working fine on the iPhone doesn't mean the error does not exist.

Try enabling NSZombieEnabled

1. You can do by clicking on 'Product' in the Xcode top bar.
2. Press the option key and click on run.
3. Under environment variables click +
4. Added NSZombieEnabled and set its value to YES

This should give you more details about the object you're trying to access and help you debug the issue.

Comment: Hi, found the problem which caused error. Location service seems not working on ios simulator. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the keyboard settings on the simulator and turn everything off.

Answer (score 0):

Did you uninstall Xcode via the command line before you installed the new version? This is a crucial step that many seem to be missing.